# Explaining the 'find -mtime' command

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to remove all the dated logs except the most recent. Before I execute a script to remove the files, I want to of course test my commands to make sure I'm bringing up accurate results.

When executing these commands the date is:

```
Sep  1 00:53:44 AST 2014
```

Directory Listing:

```
Aug 27 23:59 testfile.2014-08-27.log
Aug 28 23:59 testfile.2014-08-28.log
Aug 29 23:59 testfile.2014-08-29.log
Aug 30 23:59 testfile.2014-08-30.log
Aug 31 23:59 testfile.2014-08-31.log
Sep  1 00:29 testfile.log
```

I thought -mtime +1 was supposed to list all files over a day old. Why isn't the 8-30.log one listed?

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -name "testfile*log"
./testfile.2014-08-27.log
./testfile.2014-08-28.log
./testfile.2014-08-29.log
```

This is the desired effect, but it was just trial and error. What is this 0 saying?

```
find . -type f -mtime +0 -name "testfile*log"
./testfile.2014-08-30.log
./testfile.2014-08-27.log
./testfile.2014-08-28.log
./testfile.2014-08-29.log
```

Comment: The question is not exact: "most recent" is as of my understanding something like "latest" or "youngest" - this is something other than "the last 24 hours" what the example shows.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The POSIX specification for [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) says:

> `-mtime`*`n`*
> The primary shall evaluate as true if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 (with any remainder discarded), is *`n`*.

Interestingly, the description of `find` does not further specify 'initialization time'.  It is probably, though, the time when `find` is initialized (run).

> In the descriptions, wherever *`n`* is used as a primary argument, it shall be interpreted as a decimal integer optionally preceded by a plus ( '+' ) or minus-sign ( '-' ) sign, as follows:
>
> *`+n`*
> More than *`n`*.
>   *`n`*
> Exactly *`n`*.
> *`-n`*
> Less than *`n`*.

<sup>*Transferring the content of a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-the-find-mtime-command/25599430#comment82518585_25599430) to this answer.*</sup>

> You can write `-mtime 6` or `-mtime -6` or `-mtime +6`:
>
> - Using `6` without sign means "equal to 6 days old — so modified between 'now - 6 * 86400' and 'now - 7 * 86400'" (because fractional days are discarded).
> - Using `-6` means "less than 6 days old — so modified on or after 'now - 6 * 86400'".
> - Using `+6` means "more than 6 days old — so modified on or before 'now - 7 * 86400'" (where the 7 is a little unexpected, perhaps).

At the given time (2014-09-01 00:53:44 -4:00, where I'm deducing that AST is Atlantic Standard Time, and therefore the time zone offset from UTC is -4:00 in ISO 8601 but +4:00 in ISO 9945 (POSIX), but it doesn't matter all that much):

```
1409547224 = 2014-09-01 00:53:44 -04:00
1409457540 = 2014-08-30 23:59:00 -04:00
```

so:

```
1409547224 - 1409457540 = 89684
89684 / 86400 = 1
```

Even if the 'seconds since the epoch' values are wrong, the relative values are correct (for some time zone somewhere in the world, they are correct).

The *`n`* value calculated for the 2014-08-30 log file, therefore, is exactly `1` (the calculation is done with integer arithmetic), and the `+1` rejects it because it is strictly a `> 1` comparison (and not `>= 1`).

Comment: Simpy, please.. 
If user want to get file modified 2 days AGO and older- 3 days, 4,.., he has to set `mtime to +1`?  In this case minus case is little nonse- pointer to the future? :D 
Am I right? :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. However, you can write `-mtime 6` or `-mtime -6` or `-mtime +6`. The `6` without sign means "equal to 6 days old — so modified between 'now - 6 * 86400' and 'now - 7 * 86400'" (because fractional days are discarded), while `-6` means "less than 6 days old — so modified since 'now - 6 * 86400'" and `+6` means "more than 6 days old — so modified on or before 'now - 7 * 86400'" (where the 7 is a little unexpected, perhaps). If that doesn't help (or you can demonstrate it's wrong), please ask again, explaining your problem more clearly.

Comment: Aw, thanks mate, that is exactly what didnt made me the sense :) So the number still means the barrier "in the past", ans sign just tells on which side of interval files should be, nice explanation :)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler your comment made more sense then the answer. x). One just want a simple understanding and suddenly... UTC ISO8601... ISO9945...POSIX...1409547224 - 1409457540 = 89684...  Comment really helped. Thanks.

Comment: Hindi isn't an approved language on this site.  Google identifies "kehna kya chahte ho?" as being Hindi for "What do you want to say?" — which is a good question for you to answer, @achhainsan, in English.

Answer (score 24):

+1 means 2 days ago. It's rounded.

Comment: The core point of this answer is correct, but it is missing a good deal of explanation.  `+1` means 2 or more days ago (or at least 2 days ago).  It would be helpful to quote a manual page, or something similar.

Answer (score 11):

To find all files modified in the last 24 hours use the one below. The -1 here means changed 1 day or less ago.

```
find . -mtime -1 -ls
```

Comment: or fine tune for just below "-1" e.g. use "-mmin -360" or "-mtime -0.25" for the last 6 hours.

Comment: `find: -mtime: -0.25: bad unit '.'`

Comment: @alper sorry don't see a problem here. mtime paramater doesn't have to be an integer necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

```
#{user} is user-name
#name of script is 'place.{user}'
#used manually or from cron
#moves files that are created by automated job queue at night 
 for the user and identified by find into dated 
 subdirectories in user's home directory, so moves them 
 from"
 /u/home/{user} to /u/home/{user}/2022/05/05 on the 5th of 
 May in 2022.

cd /u/home/{user}/
place=`date '+./%Y/%m/%d/'`;
find ./*.csv -mtime -.6 -exec mv {} $place \;
find ./*.txt -mtime -.6 -exec mv {} $place \;
find ./*.tab -mtime -.6 -exec mv {} $place \;
find ./*.pdf -mtime -.6 -exec mv {} $place \;
cd $place
chmod 666 ./*
chown {user} ./*
chgrp users ./*
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).