# Shell command to delete folders less than N days

Tags: linux, bash, shell, removeall

This is slightly different question/variation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days)

1. Remove all directories whose created on time is older than N days.
2. Don't consider the sub-directories/files within the directory.

Ex:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Aug 26 14:42 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201408261440_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  1 05:13 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201408281233_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  1 10:06 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201409011001_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  1 15:58 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201409011554_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  2 15:11 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT_201409021508_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  2 15:18 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT_201409021515_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  5 13:05 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT_201409051303_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  5 15:32 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201409051528_1
drwxrwxr-x 6 test test 4096 Sep  8 11:54 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT_201409081152_1
```

I should be able to delete all folders in this path whose created on is older than N days. The inside folder might have updated files/sub-directories which are new, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete old directories:

```
N=4
find . -type d -mtime +$N -exec rm -fr {} +
```

A depth-first search would ensure that sub-directories are removed before the directories that contain them, but might end up altering the modify time on the directory before `find` looks at it, which would mean that directories that were old are no longer counted as old.  However, conversely, the `rm` may end up trying to remove directories it has already removed, but the `-f` option ensures this does not end up with error reports.

You might want to consult [Explaining `find … -mtime` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-find-mtime-command/25599430#25599430) for information about the meaning of `+$N` vs `-$N` vs `$N` (where `N` is assumed to hold a number).