# Using find to locate files modified within yesterday

Tags: shell, find

I would like to get a shell command to find the files with a modification date for yesterday — 24 hours only. That means I would like to find the files which were modified yesterday only.

Comment: Suppose you run the command at 10:00 on 2016-07-14.  Are you looking for files modified between 2016-07-13T00:00:00 and 2016-07-13T23:59:59 (all in your current time zone)?  Or are you looking for files modified in the last 24 hours, in which case the range is between 2016-06-13T10:00:00 and 2016-07-14T10:00:00?  Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use find with `mtime` and `daystart`, it will find files modified 1*24 hours ago, starting calculations from midnight (daystart):

```
find dir -daystart -mtime 1
```

Comment: See [Explaining `find -mtime` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-find-mtime-command/25599430?s=1|4.3858#25599430) — I think that does not do what is required yet.

Comment: Right, but it will do the correct thing when combined with `-daystart` (that is find files from yesterday between 0:00 and 23:59)

Comment: Yup — `-daystart` works, assuming you are using GNU `find`.  (BSD / Mac OS X `find` does not support `-daystart`, for example, even though it does support `-newermt` and related options.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you have GNU [`date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Options-for-date.html) and [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Comparing-Timestamps).  It also assumes that if you run the script at any time on 2016-07-14, you want the files modified at or after 2016-07-13T00:00:00 and before 2016-07-14T00:00:00.

If those assumptions are correct, then you can use:

```
find .  -newermt "$(date -d yesterday +'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" \
    '!' -newermt "$(date -d today     +'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')"
```

The first command substitution generates (on 2016-07-14) the output `2016-07-13 00:00:00` and the second `2016-07-14 00:00:00`.  The `-d today` is not needed to get the right result, but shows the symmetry.

The condition overall means 'modified at or after midnight yesterday morning and not modified since midnight this morning'.

It is harder to do this on systems without GNU `date` to evaluate the different dates.

See [Explaining `find -mtime` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-find-mtime-command/) for information on why using `-mtime` will not meet the assumed requirements.