# AIX - how to list files of today's date

Tags: shell, file, aix

What is the command to list files in a directory of today's date in AIX? The commands from Unix and Linux don't all work in AIX.

Comment: What's wrong with `find directory -type f -mtime 0`?

Comment: Mind you, file dates are stored as unix timestamp, so the meaning of 'today' depends on your timezone; for example the file might have been created on 2021-07-02 in Australia, while there is 2021-07-01 in my timezone.

Comment: @Darkman — See [Explaining the `find -mtime` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25599094/15168) for a description of how `-mtime` works (based on POSIX; maybe that should be "how `-mtime` should work"), and therefore you can work out what's wrong with using `find directory -type f -mtime 0`.  TL;DR — `-mtime 0` means "in the last 24 hours", not "during the current day measured from midnight local time" (which is what I think the OP wants).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes I know that. I just want to know what the OP mean by ***"don't all work in AIX."***. What the OP wants is probably: `find directory -type f -daystart -ctime 0`

Comment: Using `-daystart` wouldn't work on macOS   unfortunately.  And it doesn't work on AIX either.  According to the man page for `find` on AIX 7.2, it supports the conditions `-amin`,
`-atime`,
`-cmin`,
`-cpio`,
`-ctime`,
`-depth`,
`-ea`,
`-follow`,
`-fstype`,
`-group`,
`-inum`,
`-links`,
`-iregex`,
`-long`,
`-ls`,
`-mmin`,
`-mtime`,
`-name`,
`-newer`,
`-nogroup`,
`-nouser`,
`-perm`,
`-size`,
`-regex`,
`-regextype`,
`-size`,
`-type`,
`-user`,
`-xdev`.  Using `-newer` is likely the best option. as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226289/15168).

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from [a POSIX solution at U&L to a similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588814/117549) by Stéphane Chazelas, this will find *files* (`-type f`) under /path/to/directory, recursively, that have a modification time of today's date (starting from midnight):

```sh
touch -t "$(date +%Y%m%d0000)" ~/.today &&
  find /path/to/directory -type f -newer ~/.today
rm ~/.today
```

... where you put the ~/.today timestamp file outside of /path/to/directory, of course.

Alternatively, the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-downloads-alpha#Z) site has packaged zsh and its dependencies, so you could download and install those, then use the ["age" function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Calendar-Function-System.html#Glob-qualifiers) as a [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-globbing_002c-qualifiers):

```
zsh
autoload age
print -- /path/to/directory/*(.e:age today:)    ## non-recursive
print -- /path/to/directory/**/*(.e:age today:) ## recursive
```

The `.` in the glob qualifier restricts matches to files; the `e: ...:` creates an expression that is called for each file to determine inclusion/exclusion.

Hat tip again to Stéphane for demonstrating that age function in [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232034/117549).